# How to concatenate two dataframes by renaming them according to data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Hey I want to concatenate two dataframes df1 and df2.
But i want them to be renamed according to dataframe as i wnat to compare each column.

I have a Pandas Dataframe df1 as shown below:

```
    1       2       3
 0  a       p       q
 1  b       n       r
 2  c       o       s
```

IAnd another  Pandas Dataframe df2 as shown below:

```
    1    2       3
 0  a    t    read
 1  b    l  unread
 2  c    w    read
```

I want to concat them also rename the column according to respective datafarame :

```
    df1_1   df2_1   df1_2  df2_2  df1_3  df2_3
 0  a       a       p       t      q      read
 1  b       b       n       l      r      unread
 2  c       c       o       w      s      read
```

Also i want the columns to be re arranged accordingly s that i can compare.
Kindly provide solution to this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.join()` with the parameters  `lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2'`.

**Example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2], 2:[3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2], 2:[3,4]})
df1 = df1.join(df2,  lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2')
df
>>>
   1_df1  2_df1  1_df2  2_df2
0      1      3      1      3
1      2      4      2      4
```

Maybe this is close enough. If not you can rename the columns afterwards, using this line:

```
df1.rename({name: name.split('_')[1] +'_'+ name.split('_')[0] for name in df1.columns}, 
           axis=1)
>>>
   df1_1  df1_2  df2_1  df2_2
0      1      3      1      3
1      2      4      2      4
```

Comment: Hm, wasn't `add_prefix` option already there in my answer before you added it to yours?

Comment: Yes. it's true. I can remove it, if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, thanks, in general it's preferred that you only add solutions that are distinct from other answers

Answer (score 1):

Using `add_prefix` and then rearranging columns with `reshape`:

```
x1 = df1.add_prefix('df1_')
x2 = df2.add_prefix('df2_')

cols = np.vstack((x1.columns, x2.columns)).T.reshape(-1)

x1.join(x2).reindex(cols, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  df1_1 df2_1 df1_2 df2_2 df1_3   df2_3
0     a     a     p     t     q    read
1     b     b     n     l     r  unread
2     c     c     o     w     s    read
```